# Return unique results in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a use case in which I have data like

```
{
    name: "John",
    parentid": "1234",
    filter: {a: '1', b: '3', c: '4'}
},
{
    name: "Tim",
    parentid": "2222",
    filter: {a: '2', b: '1', c: '4'}
},
{
    name: "Mary",
    parentid": "1234",
    filter: {a: '1', b: '3', c: '5'}
},
{
    name: "Tom",
    parentid": "2222",
    filter: {a: '1', b: '3', c: '1'}
}
```

**expected results:**

```
bucket:[{
    key: "2222",
    hits: [{
        name: "Tom" ...
    }, 
    {
        name: "Tim" ...
    }]
},
{
    key: "1234",
    hits: [{
        name: "John" ...
    },
    {
        name: "Mary" ...
    }]
}]
```

I want to return unique document by `parentid`. Although I can use top aggregation but I don't how can I paginate the bucket. As there is more chance of `parentid` being different than same. So mine bucket array would be large and I want to show all of them but by paginating them.

Comment: [Paging support for aggregation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) is not implemented yet. Please show a sample response you'd like to get, maybe there's another way to get you what you need.

Comment: i have updated with expected result's now my length of bucket will be  much larger. so how do i approach this problem.

Comment: It seems you're aggregating by `parentid` and not by "filter attributes" as stated in your question. Your objective is not very clear, please make sure to update your question to reflect exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing this. But you can follow these steps to get desired result.

**Step 1.** You should know all `parentid`. This data can be obtained by doing a simple `terms aggregation` (Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation)) on field `parentid` and you will get only the list of `parentid`, not the documents matching to that. In the end you will have a smaller array on than you are currently expectig.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "parentids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parentid",
        "size": 0 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`size: 0`  is required to return all results. Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size).

OR

If you already know list of all `parentid` then you can directly move to step 2.

**Step 2.** Fetch related documents by filtering documents by `parentid` and here you can apply pagination.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20, 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "parentid": "2222"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

`from` and `size` are used for pagination, so you can loop through each of `parentid` in the list and fetch all related documents.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking for all names grouped by parent id, you can use below query:

```
 {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },"aggs": {
        "parent": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "parentid",
            "size": 0
          },"aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "name",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },"size": 0
    }
```

If you want the entire document grouped by parentdId, it will be a 2 step process as explained by Sumit above and you can use pagination there.

Aggregation doesn't give you access to all documents/document-ids in the agg result, so this will have to be a 2 step process.

Comment: Is there a way to paginate in sub-aggregation?

Comment: @SumitKumar Updated my answer. From the question it looked like he was only looking for names for all parent id. No there is no way currently to paginate over aggregation result.